Test Script generating binary body with encryption and replay is not working properly
Currently I am working on the Oracle EBS application performance testing using LoadRunner tool.
VuGen version - 24.1
Oracle Form Version : 12.0.14.12020000.22
After log into the EBS application, I need to click on values option then it will download FRMservlet.jnlp file once I click on downloaded file it will open java web launcher page. In that page need to choose values from the dropdown and need to pass unique entries in the next page.
Test script recorded in multi (Web http/html + Oracle NCA) protocol mode and below is the request details.
We found that all the request body related to java web launcher page is recorded in binary/encrypted Format which we could not able to enhance.
After replaying the script, In replay log jsessionidforms correlation is captured and not getting any http error but I can see ifError:7/500
As per my understanding, response body is encrypted and which is not able to decrypt by VUGen therefore it's generating those binary code and not replying correctly. How can I fix the scripting issue?
web_custom_request ( "URL=../forms/lservlet;JsessionIDForms={C_JsessionIDForms}", "Method=POST", "Resource=0", "RecContentType=application/octet-stream", "Referer=", "Snapshot=t108.inf", "Mode=HTTP", "EncType=application/octet-stream", "BodyBinary=GDay\\xEF\\xBF\\xBD", )
Tried to decrypt request body by using on line conversion tool but unable to fix it

Not encrypted, but encoded. There is a difference.  Speak with your developer to understand the encoding model they have elected, then implement a decode and encode pair in the Data format extensions - https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/24.1/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_web_data_format_extensions.htm

Thanks for the quick response. I forgot to mention test script is 2 parts (web part + Desktop app(.jnlp file)). Unable to record Java web launcher part in LR tool as a workaround we have recorded java web launcher requests in Fiddler tool later we have converted into LR script.
Fiddler Reuest Body : GDayçC
Loadrunner Request Body : GDay\xEF\xBF\xBD
Contacted with Dev team for encoded logic, They are saying not aware about encoded logic and connect with Product team to get the details but we don't have Product team contact. Is there any other way to fix this issue? Please help.

By the way, the LoadRunner proxy recorder is just a reskinned version of Fiddler.
